# Limitar contenido segun usuario

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, formularios

Tengo una duda sobre como limitar las opciones que ve un usuario dentro de un formulario en my select/option 
Quiero que el usuario id =1 solo pueda ver los clientes que le asigne (digamos el cliente1 y clientes5 )
 
Tengo la libertad de agregar campos para este proposito en mi base de datos ***usuarios*** y ***clientes*** las cuales son:

***usuarios***

```
id nombre usuario contraseña tipoUsuario
1  Miguel us1     psw1       1
2  Pedro  us2     psw2       1
3  Lalo   us3     psw3       2
4  Juan   us4     psw4       2
5  Diego  us5     psw5       3
```

***clientes***

```
idCliente  cliente
1          cliente1
2          cliente2
3          cliente3
4          cliente4
5          cliente5
```

Mi intencion es que es que puedan ver en mi conbsulta unicamente sus clientes asignados.

Estoy usando un campo Select donde muestro todos los clientes de la tabla ***clientes*** :

```
        <?php
$conn //aqui tengo la conecion a la base de datos

            session_start();
                include "../controler/conn.php";
                if (!isset($_SESSION['user_log'])&& $_SESSION['user_log']==null) {
               header("location: ../action/logout.php");
           }
            $id=$_SESSION['user_log'];
            $query=sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT * from usuarios WHERE correo='$id'");
            while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)) {
$tt_usuario_id = $row['id']; //el id del usuario 
        ?>

          <select name="cliente" >
            <option value="" >--Select--</option>
              <?php
$sqlCliente = "SELECT * FROM clientes";//aqui es donde agregaria el where 

                  $resultCliente = sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlCliente);
                        while($rowCliente = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultCliente) )
                        { 
                        $idClienteSelect= utf8_encode($rowCliente['idCliente']); 
                        $clienteSelect  = utf8_encode($rowCliente['cliente']);
              ?>
            <option value ="<?php echo $idClienteSelect;?>">
              <?php echo $clienteSelect;?>
            </option>
                <?php } ?>        
          </select>
```

Como mencione me gustaria saber cual seria un buen metodo en my where o queagregar en la base de datos parapoder asignar clientes a los suarios y poder mostrar unicamente lo asignado (le e estado intentado pero creo que se me an acabado las ideas :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es una tabla intermedia donde asocies el id del usuario con el id de los clientes osea una tabla de 1 a muchos 1:N, donde un cliente puede ser manejado por uno o varios usuarios. Ejemplo:

```
Usuarios

id nombre usuario contraseña tipoUsuario
1  Miguel us1     psw1       1
2  Pedro  us2     psw2       1
3  Lalo   us3     psw3       2
4  Juan   us4     psw4       2
5  Diego  us5     psw5       3

Clientes

idCliente  cliente
1          cliente1
2          cliente2
3          cliente3
4          cliente4
5          cliente5

Usuario-Clientes

idUsuario idCliente
1         1
1         5
2         1
2         3
```

El query seria algo asi:

```
 SELECT * FROM usuarios u, clientes c usuarioclientes uc
 WHERE u.id = uc.idUsuario
 AND c.idCliente = uc.idCliente
```

El asterisco lo cambias por los campos que necesites. Me avisas si te sirvio.

Comment: Muchisimias gracias Devid Leonardo (mas por entenderme recien es mi primer post y soy algo nuevo en el foro jeje) lo estoy poniendo en practica

Comment: A su orden, espero haberte ayudado

Answer (score 0):

la manera que se me ocurre es crear una nueva tabla con la asignación de clientes por usuario, de esa manera un cliente incluso podría ser visto por 1 o más usuarios (si fuese el caso), lo ingresas en tu consulta con un INNER JOIN y en el WHERE le añades el id del usuario. 
Algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM CLIENTES 
INNER JOIN CLIENTES_USUARIOS ON (CLIENTES.IdCliente=CLIENTES_USUARIOS.IdCliente)
INNER JOIN USUARIOS ON (USUARIOS.Id=CLIENTES_USUARIOS.IdUsuario)
WHERE USUARIOS.Id='$id'
```

Answer (score 0):

final mente lo solucione!

lo solucione asignandoid repetidos

```
idCliente  cliente
1          cliente1
2          cliente2
2          cliente3
1          cliente4
5          cliente5
```

De esta manera el usuario puede asignarsele un valo (***1*** por ejemplo) 
y mostraria elcliente1 y cliente4  si tiene asignado eñcliente uno en ***usuarios***